# App Engine Flexible deployment fails to become healthy in the allotted time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

My flask app deployment via App Engine Flex is timing out and after setting `debug=True`. I see the following line repeating over and over until it fails. I am not sure however what this is and cannot find anything useful in logs explorer.

`Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...working DEBUG: Operation [apps/enhanced-bonito-349015/operations/81b83124-17b1-4d90-abdc-54b3fa28df67] not complete. Waiting to retry.`

Could anyone share advice on where to look to resolve this issue?

Here is my app.yaml (I thought this was due to a memory issue..):

```
runtime: python
env:flex
entrypoint: gunicorn - b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
   python_version:3

resources:
   cpu:4
   memory_gb: 12
   disk_size_gb: 1000

readiness_check:
  path: "/readines_check"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

Error logs:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2022-05-10T23:21:10.941Z47607.vt.0: Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.`

Comment: Did you try increasing `app_start_timeout_sec` to the maximum value which is `1800`? That way you can give [health check](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#updated_health_checks) a bit more time to your app to become healthy.

Comment: Hey Catherine, thanks, I tried that but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you confirm if the `splitHealthChecks` feature is enabled by running `gcloud app describe`?

Answer (score 0):

There could be possible ways to resolve such deployment errors.

1. Increase the value of `app_start_timeout_sec` to the [maximum value](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#readiness_path) which is `1800`
2. Make sure that all the Google Cloud services that Endpoints and ESP require are enabled on your project.
3. Assuming that `splitHealthChecks` feature is enabled, make sure to follow all the [steps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating-to-split-health-checks#converting_legacy_health_check_options) needed when migrating from the legacy version.

Comment: Could you explain number 2? I don't know what it means