# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] - App engine flex

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-php

I started getting this error all of a sudden when i deploy app engine flex.

The full error i get is the following

```
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError: Error Response: [4] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2024-02-11T09:54:47.328Z208.wa.2: Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.
```

This is the yaml file i use.

```
runtime: custom
api_version: '1.0'
env: flexible
service: service-name
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 15

readiness_check:
  app_start_timeout_sec: 1800

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: sql-instance

vpc_access_connector:
  name: vonnector-name
  egress_setting: all-traffic

network:
  name: network-name

includes:
  - secrets.yaml
```

I followed this from the documentation and i made sure that the services have the right permissions.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/troubleshooting#healthy-time-out

These are the following things are tried

- increased disk size
- checked ip quota limits
- deleted docker images and created new ones
- removed the network name vpc connector and sql instance from the yaml file
- I used --verbosity=debug when i deployed to get extra information but nothing useful was found.
- I tried to remove "readiness_check: app_start_timeout_sec: 1800"

Comment: Which version of Google cloud SDK are you using? Can you try updating to the latest version of [Google cloud SDK - 463.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#46300_2024-02-06) by running the command `gcloud components update` and redeploy.

Comment: Also can you try with the suggestion shared in this [Github Link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/issues/153#:~:text=running%20gcloud%20config,your%20app.yaml), [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77578704/flex-await-healthy-error-while-deployment-on-google-app-engine-flex-environment#:~) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72193928/app-engine-flexible-deployment-fails-to-become-healthy-in-the-allotted-time#:~).

Comment: i deploy from gitlab where i specify the image with the latest sdk `image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine` and therefore any fix that is related to sdk should be covered already by this image. I've seen those links and tried couple of their solutions ( basically any solution not related to google sdk ) but none of them worked.

Comment: i tried to deploy from my local machine after i ran `gcloud components update` but it didn't help, i still get the same error.

Comment: i just noticed that with `--verbosity=debug`  the following message appears `Updating service. Operation not complete. Waiting to retry.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the recent error message `Updating service. Operation not complete. Waiting to retry`.

1. It seems like the root cause of the issue is with the `Constraints`.  Can you check the activity log in the cloud console? You can refer to this [`Documentation`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints).
2. Also the above error may occur due to quotas in your project associated with App Engine and Compute Engine. Need to remember that, App Engine Flex runs in VMs. There is a similar [`Issue`](https://issuetracker.google.com/73583699), related to the quotas: `In-use IP addresses`. Also check other quotas like CPU cores, memory. Check their quotas page in Cloud Console and make sure they are not near any limits, and to request increases for those that they are near.
3. Also if you are using a [`Shared VPC configuration`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/using-shared-vpc) to deploy your application make sure that you enabled the required permissions.
4. Alternatively, Can you try running the following commands by
   replacing the field “PROJECT_ID” with your Google Cloud Project ID
   and then try redeploying which may help you in resolving the issue.

   ````
   gcloud config set interactive/hidden true

   gcloud app update--service-account=<PROJECT_ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

   gcloud config set interactive/hidden false ```
   ````
5. Also try adding a gcp-build script with an empty value in your `package.json` file as per `gcp-build`. Please refer to the [`Documentation`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step) for more information regarding adding gcp-build in your package.json file.

If the above suggestions do not help, then it might be observed that the issue is specifically for your project and requires a project inspection. It’s better to contact [`Google support`](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for the same.

Comment: the issue was due to constraints that were applied globally to all projects.